# What is the purpose of different needle felting needles?

Tags: tool-selection, felt, felting-needles

For needle felting there are different types of needle points and different sizes to choose from. How do you select the right ones/what do they do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Felting Needle Chart, via [Paradise Fibers](https://www.paradisefibers.com/pages/felting-needle-size-chart), which describes each needle type, gauge, blade style, fiber type, and uses:

[image: Needle Felting Chart]

[Additionally, here is a very helpful YouTube reviewing the types of Felting Needles, demonstrating their various uses, and mentioning safety when Felting.](https://youtu.be/02pQi_VZ8ew)